# How to use custom templates in Backbone-forms?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

There are few `forms` in my project which involve lot of validations and server calls. So, I thought of using `'backbone-forms.js'` for these. Currently I am playing around with this code : http://jsfiddle.net/evilcelery/VkUFu/  to see if `'backbone-forms.js'` caters to all my needs.

Surely we can give our own custom templates to `individual components` like 'list', 'date' etc as defined in https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#customising-templates. But in my workplace, all html templates should be independent from the javascript implementations so that the classes and markup can be edited based on the needed appearances (javascript coding is based on the field `ids` which will not be altered). My problem is that I am unable to use my own custom template for the forms built using `'backbone-forms.js'`.

Is there any way to make the template.html independent from javascript(like in case of handlebars.js) ?

Is there someway that we can use a compiled handlebars template with all form fields in the template.html and using Backbone.Form functionality or is this not possible?

Thanks.

Comment: The snippets are just strings, you could extract those strings from `<script>` containers.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks. In the <script> container, we have snippets for components like 'field', 'radio' etc. Is there some way I can define the entire template (like we do while using handlebars)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use backbone-forms (hence the comment instead of an answer) so I don't know how to make it behave sensibly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you would like to load **html templates** from individual sources dynamically (like from .../templates/category.html) instead of letting BackboneForms render it from the schema or having to define them in an ugly way in the javascript code like [here](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#customising-templates)

You can load your html template **on the go as a string with ajax** (or better, with Require.js) and call `Backbone.Form.setTemplates({templateName: templateBodyAsString})`. It won't override  other already registered templates with other names, see `setTemplates`'s implementation below.

If you use `$.ajax()`, you can put your form rendering code in the `success` callback. If you use `Require.js`, it will be easier, not to mention its caching mechanism, if all of your BB modules/forms load their own templates every time, then `Require.js` will only do the ajax request first time a module needs the same template.

**The body of the `Backbone.Form.setTemplates` function:**

```
function (templates, classNames) {
    var createTemplate = helpers.createTemplate;

    Form.templates = Form.templates || {};
    Form.classNames = Form.classNames || {};

    //Set templates, compiling them if necessary
    _.each(templates, function(template, key, index) {
      if (_.isString(template)) template = createTemplate(template);

      Form.templates[key] = template;
    });

    //Set class names
    _.extend(Form.classNames, classNames);
  }
```